# How to implement dragable UIButton in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have been trying to implement dragable UIButton in iOS by overriding touchesMoved method.
The button shows up , however i am not able to drag it.What am i missing here?
[this is what i reffered](http://iphoneapp-dev.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-drag-image-or-button-in-iphone.html)

This is my .h file.

```
 @interface ButtonAnimationViewController : UIViewController
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *firstButton;
```

And the .m file.

```
@implementation ButtonAnimationViewController

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint pointMoved = [touch locationInView:self.view];
self.firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(pointMoved.x, pointMoved.y, 73, 44);

}
```

Comment: can you log your x and y in `touchesMoved`?

Comment: well i tried logging out the position....turns out the touchesMoved method is not executing at all.

Comment: thats what i thought, is your `ButtonAnimationViewController` a sub controller of anything other controller?

Comment: NO...just plain UIViewController

Comment: The `touches…` code goes in a UIView, not a UIViewController.  You'd need to handle this in a UIButton or UIView subclass.  (A pan gesture recognizer is better for this use.)

Comment: Well...the example that i referred above...it has everything implemented in ViewController , and it worked fine , so thats exactly what i did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a fully working button dragging example using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which, in my opinion, is easier. I tested it before posting the code. Let me know if you have any more questions:

```
@interface TSViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *firstButton;

@end

@implementation TSViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // this code is just to create and configure the button
    self.firstButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [self.firstButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 40);
    [self.view addSubview:self.firstButton];

    // Create the Pan Gesture Recognizer and add it to our button
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragging:)];
    [self.firstButton addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
}

// this method will be called whenever the user wants to drag the button
-(void)dragging:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panGesture {

    // if is not our button, return
    if (panGesture.view != self.firstButton) {
        return;
    }

    // if the gesture was 'recognized'...
    if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        // get the change (delta)
        CGPoint delta = [panGesture translationInView:self.view];
        CGPoint center = self.firstButton.center;
        center.x += delta.x;
        center.y += delta.y;

        // and move the button
        self.firstButton.center = center;

        [panGesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
    }
}

@end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanx a ton Luis...it worked like a charm.Just out of curiosity , what was i doing wrong?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. With the introduction of the Gesture Recognizers now I almost never use the "touches..." methods. I guess I'd need to see the rest of your code. I'm glad this worked for you and thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: Thanx :-) ... I guess i will have to look into gesture recognisers now.